# Figuring out which Activity onBackPressed is going to display

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an activity lets called it A that is started by a number of diferent activities lets call them B and C

depending on which activity im returning to by clicking the Up button or the back button i want to display two distinct transitions for example:

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    final Intent intent = NavUtils.getParentActivityIntent(this);

    NavUtils.navigateUpTo(this, intent);

    // what i want to do is 
    if(goingToB)
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.do_nothing, R.anim.slide_out_right);
    else if(goingToA)
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.do_nothing, R.anim.slide_out_bottom);
}
```

I know i can pass an extra when starting the activity specifying the transition to show on navigating back, but im wandering if there is an more elegant and easy way to achieve this

Comment: `I know i can pass an extra when starting the activity specifying the transition` that's very elegant, IMO.

Comment: Pearhaps but even more elegant would be the framework to allow to specify the "reverse" transition upon launching the same way we can do it with for starting an activity: ActivityOptionsCompat
                .makeCustomAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.slide_in_bottom, R.anim.do_nothing)
                .toBundle();   :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it seems theres no more "elegant" way.